# Property $(\mathcal{L}(\phi),\phi)\geq 0$ about a operator $\mathcal{L}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, eigenvalues

Consider the operator $\mathcal{L} : H^2(\mathbb{T}_L) \subset L^2(\mathbb{T}_L) \longrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{T}_L)$ given by
$$\mathcal{L} = -\omega \partial_x^2+3\varphi^2-1,$$
that is
$$\mathcal{L}(f) = -\omega f''+3\varphi^2f-f,$$
where $\mathbb{T}_L:= \mathbb{R}/L\mathbb{Z}$ and $L,w>0$ are fixeds constants and $\varphi$ is a fixed function. I know that $\mathcal{L}$ is linear, self-adjoint and from the Floquet Theory, the operator $\mathcal{}$ has only negative eigenvalue $\lambda <0$, with eigenfunction $\phi$.

**Question.** Why for any $\psi \in H^1(\mathbb{T}_L)$ such that $\psi \perp \phi$, that is $(\psi, \phi)_1=0$, we have
$$(\mathcal{L}(\psi),\psi)\geq 0? \tag{1}$$

Here $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denote the inner product in $L^2$ and $(\cdot, \cdot)_1$ the inner product in $H^1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\psi$ in (1)? Is $(\cdot,\cdot)_1$ the canonical inner product in $H^1$ or an equivalente one?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I meant $\phi$. Is the canonical inner product.

Comment: Thanks. (1) is true when $(\psi, \phi)=0$, inner product in $L^2$, why should it be true if they are orthogonal in $H^1$?

Comment: expand $\psi$ in an eigenbasis of $\mathcal{L}$

Comment: Why $($1$)$ is true when $(\psi, \phi)=0$?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune And if the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_1$ in $H_1 $is a (convenient) inner product equivalent to the canonical, then $(\psi,\phi)_1=0$ implies $(\psi,\phi)=0$?

Comment: If $(\psi, \phi)=0$, then do as @Fedor Petrov said. But orthogonality is sensitive to the inner product you choose.

Comment: If in $H^1$ you choose the inner product coming from $(L u,v)$, after integration by parts, this is equivalent to the original inner product in $H^1$ and the orthogonality with respect to $\phi$ is the same in this and $L^2$, since $L\phi=\lambda \phi$.

Comment: Then $\psi$ should be orthogonal to both eigenfunctions. Take the eigenbasis of $L$, that is $u=\sum_n c_n \phi_n$ and $L\phi_n=\lambda_n \phi_n$. Then $(Lu,u)=\sum_n \lambda_n |c_n|^2$ and you see that the sign depends on the positivity of $\lambda_n$ and vanishing of $c_n$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Understand. Is this property of $ (\mathcal{L} (\phi), \phi) \geq 0 $ strongly linked to the fact that $ \lambda $ is the **only** negative eigenvalue? Or does this property also apply more generally, that is, if there were more negative eigenvalues?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune thank you very much. Your help was very important.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune In the last case, we would still have $(\mathcal{L}(\psi), \psi) \geq 0$ or $(\mathcal{L}(\psi), \psi) > 0$?

Comment: Which is the last case?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune If there more eigenvalues. For instance, two eigenvalues.

Comment: If there are two negative eigenvalues and the third Is positive, It will be positive. If the third Is zero It can be zero. Everything follows from the espansione.